# Alphabet validation control

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I tried to do validation control for alphabet input. The validation somehow doesn't work. Does anyone know what did I miss in my code. Here are the jsfiddle for easy viewing http://jsfiddle.net/8fy408hL/1/. Thanks

Here are my javascript

```
 function valName (name) {
    var self = this;
    var letter = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);

    if(name.value.match(letter)) {
       alert('Input accepted');
       return true;
    } else {
       alert ('Input is numeric. Must be alphabet!');
       return false;
    }
 }

ko.applyBindings (new valName());
```

Comment: A fiddle you can't test is useless. And please state what kind of input is good for you, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it currently stands, your code to perform the regex comparison won't be called when the value changes as it isn't in a method.

You can use the Knockout subscribe method to be notified when the value of `self.name` changes. So this is how you would subscribe to a Knockout observable:

```
self.name = ko.observable('');

self.name.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    // newValue is the updated value
    // run the checks on new value here
});
```

### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fy408hL/8/)

**Markup**

```
<p>Name:
    <input data-bind="value: name" />
</p>
```

**JS**

```
function valViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var letter = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    self.name = ko.observable('');

    self.name.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (newValue.match(letter)) {
            alert('Input accepted');
        } else {
            alert('Input is not alphabet');
        }
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new valViewModel());
```

The better way would probably be to use a `computed` value, which would also get notified whenever the observable changes:

```
self.nameValid = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.name()) {
        if (self.name().match(letter)) {
            alert('Name is valid');
        } else alert('Name not valid');
    }
});
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fy408hL/10/)

Comment: No problem, just posted an update as it's probably better to use a `computed` value as opposed to subscribing.